# Interpreting coefficients on priors in Bayesian models

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

First time posting on Stack Exchange, so please go easy on me.

Suppose I estimated the following logistic regression:

$Pr(Y_i=1) = \frac{\text{exp}(\alpha + \beta_1X_{1i})}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha + \beta_1X_{1i})}$.

Furthermore, suppose values of X are unobserved. We'll assume the following about $X$:

$X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$.

Now suppose we have information about $\mu$ we want to use to model $X$ such that:

$\mu = \alpha' + \beta'_1Z_{1i}$.

For simplicity, assume that $\sigma$, $\beta_1$, $\alpha$, $\alpha'$, and $\beta_1'$ all get uninformative priors.

My question is this: How does one interpret the coefficient on $\beta_1'$? If it is positive, we could say that as $Z$ increases, our prior belief on $X$ is increasing in value, all else equal.

But that prior may not track well with the mean of the posterior distribution of $X$ if our MCMC chains eventually converge elsewhere. What are we to make of $\beta_1'$ and its effect on $\mu_i$ if the posterior mean of $X$ is (perhaps wildly) divergent from its prior?

Thanks in advance.

David